# How should I write a function to be used in Apply in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am wondering how I can write a function to be used in the `Apply` function in Mathematica? For example, I want to trivially re-implement the `Or` function, I found the following

```
Apply[(#1 || #2)&,{a,b,c}]
```

is not okay since it only `Or`'ed the first two elements in the list. Many thanks!

Comment: Looking at your profile I see you voted only twice on questions and answers. Is that because you're disappointed with the answers you see in Stack Overflow, or simply because you are forgetting to vote?

Comment: @belisarius: oh my bad. I thought accpeting an answer is good enough. Let me do that and remember this in the future. :)

Comment: Even answers that you don't accept might still be useful and worth an upvote.

Comment: @Simon, sure. I really appreciate all the answers and posts. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will work, no matter how many vars, and is a general pattern:

```
Or[##]&,
```

for example

```
In[5]:= Or[##] & @@ {a, b, c}

Out[5]= a || b || c
```

However, in the case of `Or`, this is not good enough, since `Or` is `HoldAll` and short-circuiting - that is, it stops upon first `True` statement, and keeps the rest unevaluated. Example:

```
In[6]:= Or[True, Print["*"]]

Out[6]= True

In[7]:= Or[##] & @@ Hold[True, Print["*"]]

During evaluation of In[7]:= *

Out[7]= True
```

This will be ok though:

```
Function[Null,Or[##],HoldAll],
```

for example,

```
In[8]:= Function[Null, Or[##], HoldAll] @@ Hold[True, Print["*"]]

Out[8]= True
```

and can be used in such cases (when you don't want your arguments to evaluate). Note that this uses an undocumented form of `Function`. The mention of this form can be found in the book of R.Maeder, "Programming in Mathematica".

HTH

Comment: If there was a way to subscribe to your answers, I would! Learn something new every time :-).

Comment: @Timo regrettably, Stack overflow doesn't provide that kind of feature. There has been a lot of requirements like that in [´Meta´](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but those who run the site don't want "user to user" oriented features.

Comment: @Timo Thanks. I am working on the second edition of my book, which will have much more material than the first one. The biggest problem at the moment is actually to reduce the volume but keep the information, not to increase the volume. Hopefully, some day it will be out )

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin Great news about the book :-)

Comment: @Leonid Thank you! Examples like `Function[Null, Or[#], HoldAllComplete][False, Print["*"]]` and `Function[s, Or[s], HoldAllComplete][False, Print["*"]]` vs `Function[Null, Or[##], HoldAllComplete][False, Print["*"]]` are didactic! Another good example is `Function[s, Or[s], HoldAllComplete][Sequence[False, Print["*"]]]`.

Comment: @Alexey They are supposed to be - I took this one out of the draft of the second version of my book :)

Answer (score 4):

```
Or @@ {a, b, c}
```

Equivalent

```
Apply[Or, {a, b, c}]
```

Equivalent

```
{a, b, c} /. {x_, y__} -> Or[x, y]
```

Apply works like this:

```
{2 #1, 3 #2, 4 #3} & @@ {a, b, c}  
{2 a, 3 b, 4 c}

Plus[2 #1, 3 #2, 4 #3] & @@ {a, b, c}
2 a + 3 b + 4 c
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are expecting the right thing from Apply? If you look in the documentation, http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html, you will see that Apply[f,expr] simply replaces the head of f by expr. It does *not*, in general, give f[expr].

If you wish to operate with function f onto expr, try f@expr or f[expr].

Perhaps you understand the above and your question really is, "how do I define some f that, when I do `Apply[f,{a,b,c}]`, does the same job as `Or[a,b,c]`. Is that it?